# is there a way to introduce cost for one class in h2o.glm in R?

Tags: r, h2o

I am using h2o.glm to carry out a prediction. The model requirement is as many true positives as possible at the cost of many false positives. 
In terms of accuracy or (AUC) the result of h2o.glm is pretty good, however, due to the requirements, I need to play with the cost matrix. C5.0 has a way to introduce cost matrix, for example.

I read the documentation 
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/h2o/versions/3.8.1.3/topics/h2o.glm

and checked many other resources and did not come across with a solution.

Perhaps some of you tried it. I would appreciate a hint.